# When does padding affect total width, and when doesn't it?

Tags: css

I've been learning CSS on a guess-and-check basis for nearly 1 year and one thing I still haven't been able to figure out is why adding `padding` sometimes affects the total width of the element and othertimes doesn't. Can someone explain this to me in simple terms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [**MDN - Box-sizing property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)
>
> The [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) CSS property is used to alter the default CSS box model used to calculate widths and heights of elements. It is possible to use this property to emulate the behavior of browsers that do not correctly support the CSS box model specification.

---

By default, padding is *not* included in an element's width/height calculation. It's worth pointing out that the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property is set to `content-box` in this case.

> [MDN - `content-box` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)
>
> This is the default style as specified by the CSS standard. The width and height properties are measured including only the content, but not the padding, border or margin. Note: Padding, border & margin will be outside of the box e.g. IF .box {width: 350px}; THEN you apply {border: 10px solid black;} RESULT {rendered in the browser} .box {width: 370px;}

---

If the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property is changed to `border-box`, the padding is *included* the element's width/height calculations, and so is the border.

> [MDN - `border-box` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)
>
> The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin. This is the box model used by Internet Explorer when the document is in Quirks mode. Note: Padding & border will be inside of the box e.g. IF .box {width: 350px}; THEN you apply {border: 10px solid black;} RESULT {rendered in the browser} .box {width: 350px;}

Further reading:

- [MDN box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model)
- [MDN padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)

Comment: I guess there is no harm if you add this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding to your answer. it will help OP understand concept of padding.